# Using the system function to run another .cpp file

Tags: c, text-files, program-entry-point, src

This program is a'grader' program, where I simply request the user to enter the name of a txt file and a .cpp source file which processes the txt file and gets its info. I then compile the source file along with the txt file, which outputs another text file. This new textile is then compared to the output expected(which I have been given as well.).

The system function allows users to run UNIX commands from a C program. When I am trying to compile the source file the user provides

I am getting an error saying that

> "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable.
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   sh: ./myProg: No such file or directory

The source file that I am compiling provided by my professor  has one function which looks like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  MAX_VALUES    3
#define  OUTPUT_LINES   5

int notmain(int argc, char **argv)
{
/*
 * argv is just the file name

 */
//printf(argv[1]);
int values[MAX_VALUES];
int i, j;


FILE *inputFile;
char name [20]="input.txt"; // I have included this piece of code to see if there is a correct output from the source file provided by the user. 
if ( (inputFile = fopen(name, "r") ) == NULL) {
     printf("Error opening input file.\n\n");
     exit(1);
}
for(i = 0; i < MAX_VALUES; i++)
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &values[i]);
for(i = 0; i < OUTPUT_LINES; i++){
   for (j=0; j < MAX_VALUES; j++)
      printf("%d ", values[j]*(i+1) + j);
   printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The code that I have written can be seen below: This code takes the information from the user and then compiles it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_LINES 5

int main(){
    char srcfile[200];
    char inpfile[200];
    char resultfile[200];

    printf("Please enter the name of the source file: \n");
    scanf("%s",srcfile);
    printf("Please enter the name of the input file: \n");
    scanf("%s",inpfile);
    printf("Please enter the name of the expected result file: \n");
    scanf("%s",resultfile);

    char test1 [100]="gcc -o myProg ";
    char test2 [100]="./myProg ";

    strcat(test2,inpfile);
    strcat(test2," > ");
    strcat(test2,resultfile);
    strcat(test1,srcfile);
    printf("%s\n",test1); //these are just tests 
    printf("%s",test2);  //these are just tests

    if (system(test1)) {
        printf("There is an error compiling the program  ");
    } 

    if (system(test2)!= 0) {
        printf("There is an error running the executable");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

**If you are looking for the solution I have posted it in the answers**

Comment: You should edit your previous question to include required information instead of posting a new question.

Comment: @MikeCAT i appreciate the constructed criticism, but I am more worried about fixing the error and completing my assignment than learning how to use correct etiquette on stack overflow

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) When using the '%s' format specifier, always use a max length modifier (that is one less than the length of the input buffer) so the user cannot overrun the input buffer, which would result in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  As an example, this: `scanf("%s",srcfile);` should be: `if( 1 != scanf("%199s",srcfile) ) { ///handle error and exit }`

Comment: @VarunRao you're much more likely to get fast help if you follow SO conventions.

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  (I.E. 100, 200)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest giving that magic number a meaningful name (perhaps via a #define statement) then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: the `gcc` command your using has many shortcomings.  Strongly suggest: 1) separate the compile step from the link step. 2) for compiling use:  `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu99 -o objectfilename.o`  you may also need to list include file locations: `-IpathtoIncludefiles` 3) for linking use: `gcc objectfilename.o -o executablefilename`   you may also need to list  library pathes and specific libraries: `-Lpathtolibraries -lshortlibraryname`

Comment: I stopped reading when I saw "I don't care about stack overflow rules, just fix my problem." No, those weren't the exact words but that is what I received.

Comment: You will more likely soon not be able to ask further questions if you disrespect site-rules.

Comment: here is a key detail that is not stated in the question:  `what is the problem your having?`

Comment: the file provided by your professor is NOT a stand-alone program.  What exactly is your professor expecting you to do?

Comment: Didn't mean it like that, im very big on learning how to use something by doing it. Ive used stack overflow less than 5 times in my life and coming from someone who used to post code as comments, this is pretty big improvement. @mah

Comment: Note: regarding the professors' code.  It produces two compiler warnings.  1) unused parameter: `argc`  2) unused parameter: `argv`.   When referencing some command line parameters, never reference beyond `argv[0]` without first  checking `argc` to assure the parameter actually exists

Comment: @user3629249 I agree which tells me that I should call the notmain function and pass it parameters before compiling ? Maybe this will change something

Comment: the method of checking the returned value from `system()` is not correct:  Excerpt from the man page: *The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.,  fork(2)  failed),  and  the return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,  the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).*

Comment: Suggest you speak with your professor (or TA) to clarify exactly what you are expected to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question: Can you run two c programs with 2 main functions? The answer: Yes . In order to do this you have to use the terminal to compile the program with the two main functions separately. However if they interact with one another Im afraid I don't have a solution to that  Now in this specific case here is how I did it. I went to the terminal and wrote.  **In this case I run one program which runs another program using the system function**

```
gcc -c main.c (this compiles the main function).
```

Then after that i wrote gcc -o Myprogram main.o
This will create an executable named Myprogram which you can run by writing

```
 ./Myprogram
```

In this case my main method is compiling another source file so I don't need to compile that program as well in the terminal. When i compiled this program it created an output.txt file in the same directory the executable and the source files are in.

Answer (score 0):

The file you're trying to compile doesn't have a `main` function, which is the entry point for C programs. This means that it's actually not possible to build that file alone into an executable.

If the name of the function is supposed to be `notmain` then you'll have to write another source file that has a `main` function and calls `notmain`. This second `main` would belong to the executable your program is compiling, not to your program. You would have three source files:

- Your grader program, which handles compilation.
- A sort of wrapper file that effectively does:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      notmain(argc, argv);
  }
  ```
- And finally the program to be graded.

You'll also either need to `extern` the `notmain` function or provide a header to share it. Your grader program would then compile the wrapper `main` and the source file to be graded together.

Comment: I can't have two main methods in a project @cormac-obrien

Comment: @Varun Rao Try changing `notmain()` to `main()` and test if that "works".  _Then_ we can address the "I can't have two main methods in a project" restriction.

Comment: I have tested this out a couple of hours ago having two main methods does not working unless you compile them separately @chux

Comment: @Varun Rao The "source file that ...  provided by my professor" does not need to be part of the compilation of "The code that (you) have written".  The _run_ of your program compiles the professor's code.

Comment: @VarunRao: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: @VarunRao I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: thank you, you seem to be one of the few who are trying their best to help find a solution to my problem. Luckily this homework isn't due until thursday and I will be seeing a TA and my professor very soon. I appreciate your help! @cormac-obrien